# Сгенерировать массив json из двух имеющихся

Tags: javascript, json

Есть два массива JSON:

```
tableColumn = ["name", "surname", "address"]
tableRows = [{"result":["Vova", "Ivanov", "Russia"], "id": 1},
             {"result":["Peta", "Samiev", "German"], "id": 2}]
```

Я хочу 'сгенерировать' из двух этих массивов, один:

```
resultArray = [
    {
       "name" : "Vova",
       "surname" : "Ivanov",
       "address" : "Russia", 
       "id": 1
    },
    {
      "name" : "Peta",
      "surname" : "Samiev",
      "address" : "German", 
      "id" : 2
    }
]
```

Получается, что первый массив держит в себе названия полей, а второй value этих полей.

**Вопрос**: каким способом можно реализовать такую 'генерацию' из 2 в 1?

Comment: А tableColumn всегда разный?

Comment: PloadyFree, ага, могут быть другие названия и кол-во.

Comment: А tableRows, надеюсь, всегда состоит из массива строк и id ?

Comment: PloadyFree, tableRows  так точно, из id и массива строк, length results из tableRows равен length tableColumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var tableColumn = ["name", "surname", "address"];
var tableRows = [{"result":["Vova", "Ivanov", "Russia"], "id": 1},
                 {"result":["Peta", "Samiev", "German"], "id": 2}];

var resultArray = tableRows.map(function(row) {
    var resultRow = {id: row.id};
    for (var i = 0; i < tableColumn.length; i++) {
        resultRow[tableColumn[i]] = row.result[i];
    }
    return resultRow;
});
```

Внутри [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), где преобразуем отдельный элемент, короче можно было бы написать с использованием [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
var resultRow = _.object(tableColumn, row.result);
resultRow.id = row.id;
```

PS. не стал править названия, но все понимаем, что в реальном коде лучше использовать что-то более конкретное, чем 'result'/'column'/'rows'.

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, делал такое впервые, ибо раньше приходилось лишь парсить json по готовым сущностям. Для решения этой задачи использовал *Google GSON*, он единственный был под рукой. Вот вам решение, до которого я дошёл (оно может быть не идеально, но суть должна быть понятна):

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String tableColumnJson = "tableColumn = [\"name\", \"surname\", \"address\" ]";
        String tableRowsJson = "tableRows = [{\"result\":[\"Vova\", \"Ivanov\", \"Russia\"], \"id\": 1},{\"result\":[\"Peta\", \"Samiev\", \"German\"], \"id\": 2}]";

        //  Переводим строку в объект (так проще запарсить, можно и без этого, но мне так показалось проще)
        String s = "{" + tableColumnJson + "," + tableRowsJson + "}";

        //  Парсим нашу строку
        Entity entity = new Gson().fromJson(s, Entity.class);
        Row[] tableRows = entity.getTableRows();
        String[] columnNames = entity.getTableColumns();

        //  Создаём массив Json-элементов
        JsonArray finalArray = new JsonArray();

        //  Для каждой записи создаём новый Json-объект и кладём в него нужные данные
        for (Row tableRow : tableRows) {
            JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
            int columnIdx = 0;
            for (String columnValue : tableRow.getResult()) {
                obj.addProperty(columnNames[columnIdx++], columnValue);
            }
            obj.addProperty("id", tableRow.getId());
            finalArray.add(obj);
        }

        //  Выводим результат =)
        System.out.println("resultArray = " + new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(finalArray));
    }
}

class Entity {
    private String[] tableColumn;
    private Row[] tableRows;

    public String[] getTableColumns() {
        return tableColumn;
    }

    public Row[] getTableRows() {
        return tableRows;
    }
}

class Row {
    private String[] result;
    private int id;

    public String[] getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, я уверен он справляется с задачей в окружении Java, но мне нужен был JavaScript

Comment: @AlexeyAl засыпал уже, думал, что java была..) Да ладно, мб кому-нибудь пригодится ещё

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил так,

```
var result = []

$.each(tableRows, function(){
    var dc = {};
    $.each(this.result, function(i, val){
       dc[tableColumn[i]] = val;
       result.push(dc);
    })
})
```

Comment: Это не окончательная версия, видимо, - push должен быть вне второго уровня вложенности, и `id` пока не проставляется.